# StringForm print fractions readable by ToExpression

Tags: string-manipulation, debugging

I have a function `f[x]` that takes one argument. Sometimes, the evaluation of `f` fails and then I would like to print the function call `f[x]` back to the terminal. I use the following syntax:

```
Print[ToExpression[ToString[StringForm["f[``]", x]], StandardForm, Hold]]
```

The problem arises when `x` is a fraction, e.g., `x=10^-10`. Then `StringForm` produces some string with dashes and newlines, which `ToExpression` cannot deal with. What would be the best way to print the function call as it is in a format that I can copy-paste back to the terminal?

Comment: `StringForm["f[``]", ToString[1/2, InputForm]]`

Comment: Yes, thanks. Write this as an answer and I will accept it. Incredible, though, how cumbersome mathematica is when it comes to printing debugging messages (compared to, e.g., python)

Comment: 2D and flexible typesetting comes at a price, unfortunately.

Comment: Why do you do such a double conversion, to string, then back to an expression?  Why don't you just print the thing as it is?

Comment: `call : f[x_] := If[good, result, Print@HoldForm[call]; $Failed]` would be even simpler.

Comment: Because the print command is part of `f`. That is, within the body of `f` the decision is made if the calculation failed. If it did then the debug message is printed. I'm not sure how I would achieve this with your syntax.